# What are the steps I have to follow to join a SETI programme from my location (India)?

Tags: seti

I just want to know if I can be part of a SETI project. I have gone through the SETI website, but I still didn't get enough guidance. Apart from installing the [BOINC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Open_Infrastructure_for_Network_Computing) software for letting my machine be used as part of SETI, is there another way round through which I can explore something about extraterrestrial life whether through institutions or as part of any community?

I simply do not want to be part of community which believe green men are visiting earth, but I want to be part of a genuine one. I can give inputs in computing, programming, and communications as an engineer.

Comment: Who are you? Are you an individual with no particular resources, or are you a large observatory with lots of telescope time that you don't know what to do with? The answer will certainly be different based on how you might actually be able to contribute. Your use of "I" would indicate something more like the former than the latter (and note, there's nothing wrong with that) but we generally don't like making assumptions that could turn out to be incorrect.

Comment: What kind of 'part of' do you mean - running the calculations on your PC? https://setiathome.berkeley.edu/sah_participate.php

Comment: I think that this question may be more suitable in the space exploration site.

Comment: @VictorStafusa No, such a question on Space Exploration would likely get migrated here.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling ,@JanDoggen Thanks for replying , apart from installing boinc software for letting my machine used as part of seti , is there any other way round through which I can explore something about Extra terrestrial life whether through institutions or as part of any community, I simply do not want to be part of community which believe green men are visiting earth but want to part of genuine one. I can give inputs in computing , programming , communications as engineer.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this will satisfy you, but BOINC has a point of contact listing for the SETI program (an e-mail address, if memory serves).  I would start by contacting them via e-mail and see if they need any assistance.  I believe the SETI@home project has shut down data collection for the time being because they have too much to warrant attaining more, so they probably are looking for unique ways to analyze the data that they have, and that would mean they need computing and programming expertise.